# OWIN: Issued token allows access to all sub-domain environments

Tags: c#, security, owin

I'm not too familiar with OWIN so hopefully someone can steer me into the right direction. We have an in-house application that is deployed to several environments. We use an OWN Claims service to validate users. I noticed that when I access our staging environment, after successful authentication and claims being issued by the service, the Token thats in session then also allows me to access the production URL. For example, after being authenticated on myapp-stage.mydomain.com, I can access my-prod.mydomain.com without any authentication taking place, and thats probably because ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated is already = true. Whats the best way to approach this issue?

This is what I'm thinking, and please guide me if im wrong:

Seeing as stage and prod is using the same OWIN Claims service, should I introduce a new parameter that passes the environment as part of the authentication, which then forms part of the user Identity. The second stage would then be to always validate the token on each environment, and check if that token was issued for against that environment. Will this work? And if so, where do I start?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have more subdomains, or just prod and staging?

Comment: There are several. dev, qa, qa1, stage and prod

Comment: Don't you think it's not the best idea to use the same claims service (which as I understand uses the same database) for development and production environments?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, stage and production uses the same claims service, which it should. The other environments uses another claims service. My main issue here is not really to isolate the dev & QA, but more so stage & prod. Having a stage issued token shouldnt allow me access to prod.

Comment: I didn't work specifically with OWIN claim service, but I've implemented claims-based authentication several times. In this case I indeed would add a claim indicating which environment this token is issued for. Then not just validate ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated, but also ClaimsIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "your environment claim").Value == "current environment";